# Theorem (definition) numbering

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I have two definitions defined as follows:

```
\newtheorem{definition_1}{Definition 1}[chapter]
\begin{definition_1}
    \label{def:def_1}
    Definition 1 text here.
\end{definition_1}

\newtheorem{definition_2}{Definition 2}[chapter]
\begin{definition_2}
    \label{def:def_2}
    Definition 2 text here.
\end{definition_2}
```

With references to them as

```
Definition~\ref{def:def_1}
Definition~\ref{def:def_2}
```

Both give me the same definition number (3.1). I have enabled the associated package:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You needn't define a new environment at each use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Definitions}

\begin{definition}\label{defa}
Text of the definition
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{defb}
Text of the second definition
\end{definition}

\ref{defa} and \ref{defb}
\end{document}
```

All theorem-like environment are declared *before* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: How to make this compatible with \Cref ?

Comment: @Sari Isn't it out of the box?

Comment: No, it shows ??? NUMBER.

Comment: @Sari I added `\usepackage{cleveref}` after `\usepackage{amsthm}` and changed `\ref` into `\Cref`. This [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqGca.png) shows the expected output.

Comment: Great, my cleverref was before amsthm. It worked, thank :)